# call a php function with a click of a button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

how do you call a php function with ajax or javascript or jquery?

this is my php script

```
function submitmessage() {
    $sent = date(y-m-d-h-m-s);
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO chatbox (from,to,message,sent)                            
    VALUES('$fullname','$to','$message','$sent')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: you need to pass your variable to the php file using ajax get or post method and at the php file get those variable inside the function and  after task done the response back to calling page.

Comment: Where/How does $fullname get set? (It does not get set inside the function.) Perhaps it should come from the POST like message is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the file that the AJAX call connects to be available on the server.

So lets say your function is in the file: functions.inc.php

You could have a php file that includes the functions.inc.php and calls the submitmessage function.

ajax_responder.php:

```
require_once 'functions.inc.php';    

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    submitmessage();
}
```

Now you can use the URL to the ajax_responder.php to submit messages.

With jQuery included or written into the page with form:

```
function submitmessage(){
    $.post("url_path/ajax_responder.php", { fullname: document.chatbox.fullname.value, message: document.chatbox.message.value } );
}
```

Then, instead of submitting a form, you change your submit button into a button that calls the submitmessage javascript:

```
<button onclick="submitmessage()">Submit Message</button>
```

As a side note, for security, I recommend that you do something more with the POST data to ensure that you do not get [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Since you are already using mysql functions you could try [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't quite done fleshing out my answer when I first posted. Hopefully it is a little more clear now? .. Perhaps you could post the HTML (and JavaScript) you are currently using and I can give you better code examples in my answer?

Comment: @RyanClough , please stop suggesting for people to use the outdated `mysql_*` functions. They will be [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) in foreseeable future.

Comment: @tereško I was going to recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_*, but I thought that that would be taking things a bit too far with this simple question.

Comment: @RyanClough tereško would probably like you to [read this](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).